# Bagging with knn as learners

Tags: matlab, knn, ensemble-learning

I am struggling in understanding why the matlab function fitcenseble doesn't allow to create an ensemble model using knn learners with bagging, but only with the random subspace method, which is more similar to the random forest one.

I would like to use bagging in order to compare the bagging method using different types of learners (e.g., knn and trees).

I hope you will help me, thank you in advance,

Marta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bagging is rarely used in conjunction with k-nn classifiers, as the decision surfaces are typically too stable and any multiples of datapoints in the bootstrap sample do not shift the 'weight' like in many other models. Paraphrasing (1):

The probability that any single datapoint appears at least once in a bootstrap sample is ~0.632. Consider a simple 2-class 1-NN classifier bagged with N bootstrap samples. A test datapoint can change classification only if its nearest neighbours in the learning set is not in at least half of the N bootstrap samples. The probability for this to occur is the same as the probability of flipping a weighted coin with a 0.632 probability for heads N times and getting less than 0.5N heads. As N gets larger this probability gets smaller and smaller. Similiar logic holds for multiclass problems and k-NN.

If you want to create your own bagging models you can do it with [bootstrp](https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootstrp.html). bootstrp() can be called without a function by calling:

```
[~, BootIndices] = bootstrap(N, [], Data);

BootSample = Data(BootIndices);
```

> (1) Breiman, Leo. "Bagging predictors." Machine learning 24.2 (1996):
>   123-140. Chapter 6.4.

Comment: Tapio, I'm very grateful to you for the accurate reply.
So, if I train an ensemble with the random subspace method and knn as learners, can I compare its performance with an ensemble of trees built with bagging? 
Or is it better to make the comparison with an ensemble of trees using the random forest algorithm?
Thank you again!

Comment: Depends on your application. Are you looking for the best algorithm for some specific classification problem? In that case I'd compare it to the Random Forest. Bagging the features as in the RF algorithm typically leads to less overfit as the algorithm is forced to produce alternative models, as opposed to mostly leaning on the same variable as might happen with the bagged trees. For that reason RFs are usually a better and fairer comparison to modern stuff, and at least in my mind naive bagged trees are a bit obsolete at least in the classification case.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me,
Cheers!